# How to centre-align NSTextField after setting its string value

Tags: cocoa, swift, alignment, nstextfield

There's probably a ridiculously simple solution to this (I'm almost embarrassed to ask).

Relevant code snippet from my view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: NSTextField!

@IBAction func getTimeButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    textLabel.stringValue = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
}
```

Before pressing the "Get Time" button, the "Press Button" label is centred:

[image]

After pressing the button, the label gets left-alligned:

[image]

Label attributes:

[image]

I have set the labels constraints, but the constrains seem to get "reset" when the string value is set.

How can I make the label stay centred after setting the string value?

I've also tried to add this to my controller, but to no avail:

```
let textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.CenterTextAlignment
textLabel.alignment = textAlignment
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, turn on `Draws Background` just to make sure something funny isn't happening with the label position.

Comment: Do you maybe need to set `textLabel.needsDisplay = true` after setting the alignment?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

`textLabel.alignment = .center`

I used this and it worked.

Comment: Looks like the value should now be "NSTextAlignmentCenter"

Comment: Only need `.center` now :)

Comment: This does not work for me. I do exactly as the OP. The String is not available at init time, so I have to set the string value later. But the text stays left-aligned no matter what I try.